# Is there a way to delete files of host inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, volumes

I am new to docker volumes, and my use case is the next:

I have two different containers running in the same host, and both need to read/write files from it. Is of my understanding that I should use docker volumes, but before I try that, I want to make sure that i can delete files of the host filesystem, from inside the containers (e.g. using a golang app)

Comment: A primary goal of Docker is that the container filesystems are isolated from each other and the host filesystem.  A container process can't delete (or otherwise modify) files on the host, except to the extent host directories are bind-mounted into containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you should use docker volumes. It can share the directory between the host and containers. For example, you want to read/write the file in /mnt, you can mount the /mnt to container.

```sh
docker run -it -v /mnt:/mnt ubuntu:latest touch /mnt/hello.log
```

now, /mnt/hello.log was created. And you can edit the file /mnt/hello.log in you host filesystem.

Then,

```sh
docker run -it -v /mnt:/mnt ubuntu:latest rm /mnt/hello.log
```

After the command above, the file /mnt/hello.log will be deleted from inside the container.

Actually, you can delete the file in golang, like this:

```golang
os.Remove("/mnt/hello.log")
```

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, thanks for the response, will give it a shot